# Blender Models appear discolored in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

When I import my Model from Blender to Unity the model appears discolored. For example the torso of the character model is red in Blender in Unity however it appears to be orange.
[image: Here how the Model looks in Blender]

[image: And here how it looks imported to Unity]

I tried importing the Model with and without the texture packed into the FBX file, importing the texture file seperatly. However nothing seemed to work.

Comment: This problem can be due to various reasons. including the amount of light, the exposure of the sky, and the difference in the graphic engine of the two software

Comment: Check if the difference appears in the texture or in your scene. You can toggle the light preview in edit view to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. By scaling the texture up by 8 times (8x8 --> 64x64 px) and not using infinitly small UV points it works.